# Disk IO simulator on Linux

Tags: c, linux, database, performance, io

I want to test database performance and understand how database throughput (in terms of transactions per second) depends on disk properties like IO latency and variation, write queue length, etc. Ideally, I need a simulator that can be mounted as a disk volume and has a RAM disk inside wrapped into a controller that allows to set desired IO profile in terms of latency, throughput, stability etc. I wonder is there such a simulator for Linux or what is the best way to write it in C?

Comment: that's very clever, love the question :) I've found similar things in the *kernel* for networking (configurable latency, bit error rate, etc..), and I only needed some extra modules and configuration. maybe there's something similar for regular I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking at loop device (losetup) and iostat. In general you can mount some image (from ramfs if needed) and perform all IO in this image

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using Linux's device mapper functionality to synthesize disks, more explicitly, [delay target](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/delay.txt) (for slowing down/splitting I/O) and [flakey target](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/dm-flakey.txt) (for making the "disk" unreliable).